# Trying to shorten my code to make multiple modals work javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, short

I am trying to make modal-contents on 5 images, I've tried for several hours to shorten my code with for loops but I still have lots of lines which I don't know how to shorten. I'm just starting with javascript. This is my code below, working but way too long.

```
var modal = [];
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    modal[i] = document.getElementById('simplemodal'+i);
}

var modalbtn = [];
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    modalbtn[i] = document.getElementById('pics-post'+i);
    modalbtn[i].addEventListener('click', eval('openmodal'+i));
    window.addEventListener('click', eval('clickoutside'+i));
}


var closebtn0 = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[0];
var closebtn1 = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[1];
var closebtn2 = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[2];
var closebtn3 = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[3];
var closebtn4 = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[4];


for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    eval('closebtn'+i.addEventListener('click', eval('closemodal'+i)));
}


function openmodal0(){
    modal[0].style.display = 'block';
}
function openmodal1(){
    modal[1].style.display = 'block';
}
function openmodal2(){
    modal[2].style.display = 'block';
}
function openmodal3(){
    modal[3].style.display = 'block';
}
function openmodal4(){
    modal[4].style.display = 'block';
}


function closemodal0(){
    modal[0].style.display = 'none';
}
function closemodal1(){
    modal[1].style.display = 'none';
}
function closemodal2(){
    modal[2].style.display = 'none';
}
function closemodal3(){
    modal[3].style.display = 'none';
}
function closemodal4(){
    modal[4].style.display = 'none';
}
function closemodal5(){
    modal[5].style.display = 'none';
}


function clickoutside0(e){
    if(e.target == modal[0])
        modal[0].style.display = 'none';
}
function clickoutside1(e){
    if(e.target == modal[1])
        modal[1].style.display = 'none';
}
function clickoutside2(e){
    if(e.target == modal[2])
        modal[2].style.display = 'none';
}
function clickoutside3(e){
    if(e.target == modal[3])
        modal[3].style.display = 'none';
}
function clickoutside4(e){
    if(e.target == modal[4])
        modal[4].style.display = 'none';
}
```

I've tried to use eval to increment the variables name but was not able to find the right way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put everything into a single loop and use anonymous functions.

```js
var modal = [];
var modalbtn = [];
var closebtn = [];
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {

    modal[i] = document.getElementById('simplemodal'+i);

    modalbtn[i] = document.getElementById('pics-post'+i);
    modalbtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal[i].style.display = 'block';
    });
    window.addEventListener('click', eval('clickoutside'+i));

    closebtn[i] = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[i];
    closebtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal[i].style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common function for opening model and closing model like:

```
function openmodel (i) {
  model[i].style.display = 'block'
}

function clickoutside(e, i){
    if(e.target == modal[i])
        modal[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

And change you event listener like:

```
modalbtn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
  openmodel(i)
})
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   clickoutside(e, i)
})
```

And insted of this

```
eval('closebtn'+i.addEventListener('click', eval('closemodal'+i)))
```

you can use:

```
var closebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')
for (let i = 0; i < closebtn.length; i++) {
  closebtn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    closeModel(i)
  })
}
```

And change closeModel function like:

```
function closemodal(i){
    modal[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```